# No sound from EasyCAP on OpenSuse Leap 42.3

Tags: audio, opensuse, usb-audio

I picked up an EasyCap but can't get any sound from it, video works fine.

if I do lsusb I find the device (ID eb1a:2861 eMPIA Technology, Inc.)

I also see the device in pavucontrol (and alsamixer), the device has one Port or channel or what to call it (Port seem to be the name pavucontrol used), called Line In it is not muted and has volume, but I get no readings from it, like if there were no sound sent at all.

For reference I am running on an Asus ROG laptop. And it has three outlits for audio. Headphones jack (I can't find that one in pavu or alsamixer), it also has a line in which I think works and overtakes the built in microphone when used, and lastly it has a line out which I currently use to get sound to my headphones as I can't get it from the headphones jack. So perhaps it is related?

My main problem now is that I have no clue how to continue troubleshooting and any pointers would be appreciated, at least in what ball park we are, do I have to compile a kernel extension or change a black-listed file you know?

Thanks for reading and any help figuring this out!

Edit (I think the relevant part is the output of $> dmesg | grep em28)

```
[   16.370983] em28xx: New device   @ 480 Mbps (eb1a:2861, interface 0, class 0)
[   16.370985] em28xx: Video interface 0 found: isoc
[   16.371004] em28xx: chip ID is em2860
[   16.461559] em2860 #0: board has no eeprom
[   16.525339] em2860 #0: No sensor detected
[   16.531764] em2860 #0: found i2c device @ 0x4a on bus 0 [saa7113h]
[   16.546989] em2860 #0: Your board has no unique USB ID.
[   16.546991] em2860 #0: A hint were successfully done, based on i2c devicelist hash.
[   16.546993] em2860 #0: This method is not 100% failproof.
[   16.546994] em2860 #0: If the board were missdetected, please email this log to:
[   16.546995] em2860 #0:       V4L Mailing List  <linux-media@vger.kernel.org>
[   16.547001] em2860 #0: Board detected as EM2860/SAA711X Reference Design
[   16.625341] em2860 #0: Identified as EM2860/SAA711X Reference Design (card=19)
[   16.625345] em2860 #0: analog set to isoc mode.
[   16.625378] em28xx audio device (eb1a:2861): interface 1, class 1
[   16.625392] em28xx audio device (eb1a:2861): interface 2, class 1
[   16.625454] usbcore: registered new interface driver em28xx
[   16.907314] em2860 #0: Registering V4L2 extension
[   17.545714] saa7115 3-0025: saa7113 found @ 0x4a (em2860 #0)
[   18.329462] em2860 #0: Config register raw data: 0x10
[   18.353378] em2860 #0: AC97 vendor ID = 0x414c4760
[   18.365418] em2860 #0: AC97 features = 0x0000
[   18.365421] em2860 #0: Unknown AC97 audio processor detected!
[   20.769853] em2860 #0: V4L2 video device registered as video1
[   20.769861] em2860 #0: V4L2 VBI device registered as vbi0
[   20.769863] em2860 #0: V4L2 extension successfully initialized
[   20.769865] em28xx: Registered (Em28xx v4l2 Extension) extension
[   21.353059] em2860 #0: Registering snapshot button...
[   21.353158] input: em28xx snapshot button as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/input/input16
[   21.353239] em2860 #0: Remote control support is not available for this card.
[   21.353242] em28xx: Registered (Em28xx Input Extension) extension
```

But just so you have all the information here is [full dmesg output](http://qrikko.com/dmesg_output.txt)

Comment: Please edit question with output of `dmesg` aftger you plug in the EasyCAP, so we can see which driver picks it up. Use `alsamixer` to see if there are any controls you may need to unmute or set to some value. `pavucontrol` has volume meters in the `Input Devices` panel, do you see any movement on it when you should have sound? If yes, you just need to set the correct recording source for your application.

Comment: Thank you @dirkt, as far as I can tell I can find controls in `alsamixer`, and in `pavucontrol`, I **don't** see any movement on the volume meters. I do hear the sound when I connect the cable to my tv.

Comment: `Unknown AC97 audio processor detected!` looks like the driver may not be able to handle your hardware. File a bug at whatever kernel bugtracker handles `em2860` (or lookup the source, and email the authors directly). The developers may be able to help (or not, without direct access to your type of hardware).

Comment: Oh, and before you do that, upgrade your kernel to the newest version - maybe there'a already code in a newer version that handles your AC97 audio processor.